# Flutter Spotfy sdk authentication issue in release builds

Tags: flutter, dart, spotify

I am facing an issue in flutter release build for spotify sdk authentication issue.it is working fine in debugging mode and connecting with spotify but in release mode its showing an error : [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(authenticationTokenError, Authentication went wrong, AUTHENTICATION_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE, null).code: PlatformException(authenticationTokenError, Authentication went wrong, AUTHENTICATION_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE, null).message

Answer (score 0):

Check your debug console while debugging the debug apk and if there are exceptions caught, then fix those exceptions, your issue will be resolved

Answer (score 0):

can you check the SH1 value of release buildType to be same as SH1 value that was given while creating the app in spotify dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

What fixed it for me was to set the *applicationId* in the *build.gradle* file (android -> app -> build.gradle).

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example" // <-
    minSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion')
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

The *applicationId* have to be the same as the **Android Package** name in you Spotify App config

[Android Package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPYSs.png)